# Streaming wcf service returning corrupt streamed file

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service that returns a stream object. But for some reason i get a corrupt zip file back which i am streaming. All the code is below Please advise

**Contract Code**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.acme.it/2009/04/01")]
public interface IFileTransferService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    FileDownloadReturnMessage DownloadFile(FileDownloadMessage request);

    [OperationContract()]
    string HellowWorld(string name);

}

[MessageContract]
public class FileDownloadMessage
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public FileMetaData FileMetaData;
}

[MessageContract]
public class FileDownloadReturnMessage
{
    public FileDownloadReturnMessage(FileMetaData metaData, Stream stream)
    {
        this.DownloadedFileMetadata = metaData;
        this.FileByteStream = stream;
    }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public FileMetaData DownloadedFileMetadata;
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream;
}


[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.acme.it/2009/04/01")]
public class FileMetaData
{
    public FileMetaData(string [] productIDs, string authenticationKey)
    {
        this.ids = productIDs;
     this.authenticationKey= authenticationKey;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductIDsArray", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public string[] ids;
    [DataMember(Name = "AuthenticationKey", Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public string authenticationKey;
}
```

**SVC file code**

```
public class DownloadCoverScan : IFileTransferService
{
    public FileDownloadReturnMessage DownloadFile(FileDownloadMessage request)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Pictures.zip", FileMode.Open,
                                           FileAccess.Read);
        FileMetaData metaData= new FileMetaData(new string[] { "1", "2" },"asd");
        FileDownloadReturnMessage returnMessage =
            new FileDownloadReturnMessage(metaData,stream);
        return returnMessage;
    }
    public string HellowWorld(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

**Config code**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DownloadCoverScanBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DownloadCoverScanBehavior" name="DownloadService.DownloadCoverScan">
    <endpoint address="" name="basicHttpStream" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpLargeMessageStream"
              contract="DownloadService.IFileTransferService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpLargeMessageStream" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"  messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client Code**

```
FileMetaData metaData = new FileMetaData();
metaData.ProductIDsArray = new string[] { "1", "2" };
metaData.AuthenticationKey = "test";
FileDownloadMessage inputParam = new FileDownloadMessage(metaData);
FileTransferServiceClient obj = new FileTransferServiceClient();
FileDownloadReturnMessage outputMessage = obj.DownloadFile(inputParam);
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[8192];
int byteRead = outputMessage.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testFile.zip");
Stream outStream = Response.OutputStream;
while (byteRead > 0)
{
    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
    byteRead = outputMessage.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
outputMessage.FileByteStream.Close();
outStream.Close();
```

Comment: Is your downloaded file the exact same size as the original file?

Comment: Well i can't open the downloaded file so can't tell if it's exactly the same

Comment: Why do you post same question twice?

Comment: @Amit I meant the exact same **size**.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. i didn't recognize that. I will delete the previous one. Thanks for pointing

Comment: @ronald-- No the size is different as well the original file is of 278 KB but the downloaded one is only 8 KB

Comment: @Ronald -- is it that i have specified the byte array  as " Byte[] buffer = new Byte[8192];
" thats why its coming as 8 kb only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be the `Content-Length` header from the response. You set it to 8192 while you actually don't know the length yet.

I'm not absolutely sure, however. Maybe it goes wrong earlier in the process. Maybe you can put some logging statement in your client code to be sure that you actually write all bytes to the output stream (by logging `byteRead` for example).

Comment: Ronald, I changed the below line and increased the size of byte array so that it can accommodate 278kb file and it started working. but i am still unsure wht size do i specify if a file is abt 300 mb

   Byte[] buffer = new Byte[355841112];

Comment: I don't think the problem was the buffer size and the code for reading from the stream doesn't contain any errors as far as I can see. I think you should try to find out why a buffer size of 8KB isn't working by adding some logging to your code. The problem with large buffer sizes is that you load the entire stream into memory and that's exactly what you want to prevent when using streams.

Answer (score 0):

This could have to do with how you close your stream on the Server side.  I had a project similar to this where the client was passing a stream in an Async call to the server, and the .zip file was corrupted sometimes.  It turned out that I wasn't closing the stream on the client side properly resulting in an incomplete stream.

I didn't see code that showed the service closing the stream it sent on the service side.

I believe a stream won't complete properly unless it's closed.  You can still read 0 bytes when it has nothing left to send though...